# Is there a way in Ruby/Rails to execute code that is in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scripting

So I have a database of different code samples (read snippets). 
The code samples are created by users. 
Is there a way in Rails to execute it?

So for example I have the following code in my database (with id=123):

```
return @var.reverse
```

Is there a way for me to execute it? Something like:

```
@var = 'Hello'
@result = exec(CodeSample.find(123))
```

So the result would be 'olleH'

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005922):

```
code = '@var.reverse'
@var = 'Hello'
@result = eval(code)  # => "olleH"
```

But be very careful in doing so; you're giving that code full access to your system.  Try out `eval('exit()')` and see what happens.

Comment: Worked like a magic.
Yes I understand that this is a security/usability issue. But this is a prototype for the internal use only and I also hope that there's a plugin that can do similar functionality but with "sandboxing", meaning letting me expose only certain ruby functions or even better just a set of methods of a certain class. I guess it's a separate discussion ;-)

Answer (score 19):

To the `eval` answer (which is the right one) I would add: get thee a copy of the Pickaxe Book (either [Programming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby) or [Programming Ruby 1.9](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9) depending on your Ruby version) and read the chapter called **"Locking Ruby in the Safe."**  That chapter is all about Ruby's safe levels and tainted objects, and the chapter opens with *exactly* your use case and why you need to be paranoid about it.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html here is the "locking Ruby in the Safe" he is talking about!

Answer (score 5):

There is also another approach which you can use if you have a very limited use case or to limit the use cases.

I had to use this approach to allow users to dynamically specify relative times e.g.`3.months.ago`

I used a regex to sanitize the input from the users like so

```
PERMITTED_OPERATIONS = /^\{\%([1-9]\.(day|year|month|hour|minute)(s\.|\.)ago|Time\.now)\%\}$/
def permit?(operation)
  return !PERMITTED_OPERATIONS.match(operation.to_s).nil?
end
```

You could extend the regex to allow for `from_now` as well or create an array of regexes for permitted operations and loop over it.

Would welcome any comments on this approach.

Comment: I modified yours to suit my needs: `^[1-9]{1,2}\.(day|year|month|hour|minute)(s\.|\.)ago$` I'm pretty sure you want to escape your periods?

Comment: @Sam Yes you are 100% correct. The periods should be escaped. I have updated the answer. Well spotted.