# Rails Action View Form Helper pass options hash to create element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, actionviewhelper

Given a hash of properties for a text_field to be made in HAML:

```
entry = {class: "form-control", disabled: true, id: :foobar}
```

How can I do this:

```
%dd!= f.send(:text_field, entry[:id], class: entry[:class], disabled: entry[:disabled])
```

But flexible? (So don't need placeholders, just a hash). Have looked at simple form docs and action view form helper docs and found `input_html`, but that's not working in this manner.

The `f.send` is obligatory, as `:text_field` can be anything. Would prefer not to use [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188893/is-there-a-way-in-ruby-rails-to-execute-code-that-is-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text_field` takes:

```
text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
```

Does

```
f.text_field(entry[:id], entry)
```

not work?

Comment: It certainly works for text_field =) But if I do `f.send(:text_field, entry[:id], entry.except(:id))` it doesn't work. If I don't find a way around this, I will use a `case` statement for all the types of inputs

Comment: `f.send(:text_field, entry[:id], entry)` ?

Comment: Nah that doesn't work. There aren't that many helpers so I don't mind typing them out