# How do I associate a Ruby script with an object and execute it on demand (in Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm interested in uploading a script (file) via my Rails application and then being able to execute this on demand.

I imagine the first step here is to handle the file upload such that I a `Model` which I can reference the file like `Model.script`. This makes sense to me.

And then from here, my plan is to expose a route/controller method which would execute this script, but I'm not sure how to handle the actual execution inside this method. For example if I had

```
class Model
  def run_script
    # logic to run self.script
  end
end
```

How would I execute the associated file/code given that it is a Ruby file? Note that the script does *not* need to run in the context of the Rails application, it just needs to run.

Comment: If you allow users to upload and run arbitrary code, they can do basically everything they want on your servers, including reading all data or secrets, sending spam, changing or deleting files, mining bitcoins, ... Usually, this is regarded as a critical remote-code-execution vulnerability. Still, if you have to execute arbitrary Ruby code you should think hard about the security and data boundaries when running the code. You might come to the conclusion to run the code in a separate sandboxed VM or to implement your feature some other way not requiring the execution of arbitrary scripts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way in Ruby/Rails to execute code that is in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188893/is-there-a-way-in-ruby-rails-to-execute-code-that-is-in-a-string)

Comment: I guess I *am* looking for a way to run this in a separate sanboxed environment is the difference here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval), which will run a Ruby script, but be very, very, careful!

For a detailed explanation see "[Code is data, data is code](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/63-eval)".

Example:

```
eval(@model_instance.script)
```

`eval` is very dangerous. If you give a user the ability to upload and run an unchecked script, it may create a huge problem. For example, someone can upload a script like this:

```
User.delete_all
```

This will delete all users from the `users` table using a SQL query without invoking any Active Record callbacks.

You can use Ruby's [`taint`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/taint) method to add some additional safety, but it is not 100% foolproof.

For a detailed example, see "[Locking Ruby in the Safe](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/taint.html)".

Comment: Is there a way to run this script outside the context of my Rails application such that something like this would not be able to happen?

Comment: @Kevin, I've updated my answer to add some safety in eval. But it's not 100%.

Comment: I see so would this be run as eval(@model_instance.script.taint) ? It seems to me that a $SAFE level of 4 would be perfectly fine for my use case, can I set this as a global variable before execution as well?

```
@model_intance.script.taint
$SAFE = 4
eval(@model_instance.script)
$SAFE = 0
```
?

Comment: You should test using $SAFE level of 4. User moderation if possible. Good luck.

Comment: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)",
"[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"
and "[Links and Hypertext - Link Text and Appearance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text)"